# One Record Per Record Multiplier

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
[Links]
LinkID, Link  
1,http:/link1  
2,http:/link2  

[Link2Page]  
LinkID, PageID

1,1  
1,2  
1,3  
2,3   
2,4  
2,5  

[Pages] PageID, Title, Url , EndPage(bit)

1, title page 1 , http:/page1 , false  
2, title page 2 , http:/page2 , true  
3, title page 3 , http:/page3 , false  
4, title page 4 , http:/page4 , false  
5, title page 5 , http:/page5 , true
```

i want to list all the Links and 1 record from pages order by endPage desc

For example

```
LinkId , Link , PageID , Title , Url  
1 , http:/link1 , 2 , title page 2 , http:/page2  
2 , http:/link2 , 5 , title page 5 , http:/page5  
...
```

The Page i select for every record exists in Link2Page is like

```
( Select TOP 1 PageID,Title,Url from Pages Order By EndPage Desc )
```

The closer i got is :

`Select LinkID , Link ,
 ( Select TOP 1 PageID From Pages Where PageID IN
 ( Select PageID From Link2Page Where Link2Page.LinkID = Links.LinkID )
 ) as PageID From Links;`

but i miss the rest of the columns ( Pages.Title , Pages.Url ) etc

Lame try ( ? ) :

> Select LinkID , Link ,
>
> ( Select TOP 1 PageID From Pages Where PageID IN ( Select PageID From Link2Page Where Link2Page.LinkID = Links.LinkID )) as PageID ,
>
> ( Select TOP 1 URL From Pages Where PageID IN ( Select PageID From Link2Page Where Link2Page.LinkID = Links.LinkID )) as URL ,
>
> ( Select TOP 1 Title From Pages Where PageID IN ( Select PageID From Link2Page Where Link2Page.LinkID = Links.LinkID )) as Title
>
> From Links;`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Links l
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 p.*
  FROM Pages p
  INNER JOIN Link2Page x ON (x.PageID = p.PageID)
  WHERE x.LinkID = l.LinkID
  ORDER BY EndPage DESC
) p
```